# How do I get the id from a XAML ListView when more than one table is used?

Tags: c#, sqlite, join

I am populating a `ListView` with SQLite data from two or more tables. When selecting from table I wish to get the ID of the selected item but `lv.SelectedItem` is returning a `null` value. No trouble with single tables.

I have searched everywhere and most people are just having problems joining the tables and haven't got as far as selecting.

## Classes

```cs
public int ShoppingListID
{
    get { return listID; }
    set { listID = value;}
}
public int ShopID
{
    get { return shopID; }
    set { shopID = value; }
}

public int ShopID
{            
    get { return shopID; }
    set { shopID = value; }
}

public string ShopName
{
    get { return shopName; }
    set { shopName = value; }
}
```

## Join code (which works perfectly)

```cs
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
{               
    var allList = (from s in conn.Table<ShoppingLists>() join p in 
                   conn.Table<Shops>() on s.ShopID equals 
                   p.ShopID select new
                   {
                       s.ShoppingListID,
                       p.ShopName
                   }).ToList();

    lvShoppingLists.ItemsSource = allList;
}
```

## Bound to a Grid in XAML

```xml
<ListView x:Name="lvShoppingLists"             
          ItemSelected="LvShoppingLists_ItemSelected"> 
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" 
                           TextColor="Black" 
                           Text="{Binding ShoppingListID}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                           TextColor="Black" 
                           Text="{Binding ShopName}" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

## Obtain the ID of the selected item

```cs
private void LvShoppingLists_ItemSelected(object sender,             
    SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
    var selectedList = lvShoppingLists.SelectedItem as ShoppingLists;
    GlobalVariables.SelectedShoppingListID = selectedList.ShoppingListID;
    Navigation.PushAsync(new ShoppingListPage());
}
```

Everything compiles and runs fine, but upon selecting an item from the `ListView` on the mainpage `var selectedList` returns a `null`.
Debug shows that the information (`id` and `Name`) is being carried to the selected item but not being converted.
The `null` value means that the variable is unable to be used in the query for the new page and I get a database error.
I suspect that it is to do with the fact that the the class Shopping list has two int entries and the name is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Answer turns out to be:

Use a new class AllLists

 public int ShoppingListID
    {
        get { return listID; }
        set { listID = value; }
    }

    public string ShopName
    {
        get { return shopName; }
        set { shopName = value; }
    }

using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
{               
var allList = (from s in conn.Table<ShoppingLists>() join p in 
               conn.Table<Shops>() on s.ShopID equals 
               p.ShopID select new **AllLists**
               {
                   ShoppingListID = s.ShoppingListID,
                   ShopName = p.ShopName
               });

lvShoppingLists.ItemsSource = allList;
}

The selected item ID can then be 
var selectedList = lvShoppingLists.SelectedItem as AllLists;
GlobalVariables.SelectedShoppingListID = selectedList.ShoppingListID;
Navigation.PushAsync(new ShoppingListPage());
```